# Reading more json strings from one file

Tags: c#, json

I've got two different json files and would like to merge them and read json strings from one file.

```
{"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1","port":80, "protocol":"http"}

{"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1", "domainName":"domain.com"}
```

I tried something, but it still doesn't work properly. I tried array and also the following structure:

```
{"jsonString1": {"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1","port":80, "protocol":"http"},
"jsonString2": {"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1", "domainName":"domain.com"}}
```

Not sure if the structure is correct. I just need to get "jsonString1", "jsonString2" separately so I don't need to use more json files.

Answer (score 2):

Your 1st fragment is non standard (effectively, not JSON).
Your 2nd IS standard, but is an object, not an array.

If you want an array, *use* an array:

```
[{"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1","port":80, "protocol":"http"},
{"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1", "domainName":"domain.com"}]
```

Alternatively, if you want to use your 2nd version (which is an object), you can access the 2 "sub-objects" by keys: `myObj.jsonString1`, `myObj.jsonString2`. BTW, A better name would be "Obj1" & "Obj2" since these are not strings, they're actual objects.

Comment: If I use the array, I can load all strings and access them by index. The issue here is that I can't specifically read "jsonString1" (I need to remember the related index).

Comment: Then use your 2nd structure, and access by keys (it's in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON Array to keep those files merged.For example

Conside,You have an JSON array for URL then and you want to print it in a paragraph then

```
<p id="url"></p>
```

declare a variable like this

```
var URL=[{"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1","port":80, "protocol":"http"},
{"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1", "domainName":"domain.com"}]
```

you can access these array by using

```
document.getElementById("url").innerHTML =
URL[0].ipAddress+ " " + URL[0].port+ " " +URL[0].protocol;
```

You can get the array values by using the index values

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I have finally used this syntax:

json:

```
{"jsonString1": {"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1","port":80, "protocol":"http"},

"jsonString2": {"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1", "domainName":"domain.com"}}
```

read the string using this command:

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
string value = jsonObject["jsonString1"].ToString();
```